# Android CursorWindowAllocationException

Tags: java, android, cursor

I'm getting this error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8223): Caused by: android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=940 (# cursors opened by this proc=940)
```

I know its probably because I'm using the Cursor in a wrong way or not closing it at the right time. I think it could be because I'm filling the same cursor without closing/emptying it?

```
public static void NextAlarmTxt(){
        int dan = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        long trenutnovrijeme = c.getTimeInMillis();
        long bazavrijeme;
        long pamti = 0;
        String danString = dani(dan);       
        Cursor CursorDan = DatabaseManager.getAllDataDay(danString);


        CursorDan.moveToFirst();
        if (!CursorDan.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {
                bazavrijeme = CursorDan.getInt(2);

                if (trenutnovrijeme<bazavrijeme)
                {
                    if (pamti==0)
                    {
                        pamti = bazavrijeme;
                    }

                    if (pamti>0)
                    {
                    if (pamti > bazavrijeme)
                    {
                        pamti = bazavrijeme;
                    }
                    }                   
                }
                if (trenutnovrijeme > bazavrijeme)
                {
                    dan = dan+1;
                    dani(dan);
                    CursorDan = DatabaseManager.getAllDataDay(danString);
                }
            }
            while (CursorDan.moveToNext());         
        }               
        CursorDan.close();
        text1.setText(new StringBuilder("Sljedeći : " ).append(pamti).toString());
    }       
    public static String dani(int dan){

    String danString = null;

        if (dan==1)
        {
        danString = "Nedjelja";
        }
        else if (dan==2)
        {
            danString = "Ponedjeljak";
        }
        else if (dan==3)
        {
            danString = "Utorak";
        }
        else if (dan==4)
        {
            danString = "Srijeda";
        }
        else if (dan==5)
        {
            danString = "Četvrtak";
        }
        else if (dan==6)
        {
            danString = "Petak";
        }
        else if (dan==7)
        {
            danString = "Subota";
        }
        return danString;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cursor Opened :

```
Cursor CursorDan = DatabaseManager.getAllDataDay(danString);
```

After that you iterate through the cursor,

```
do {
...
if (trenutnovrijeme > bazavrijeme)
                {
                    dan = dan+1;
                    dani(dan);
                    CursorDan = DatabaseManager.getAllDataDay(danString);
                }
....
}
while (CursorDan.moveToNext());
```

Now, with in the iteration loop, you overwrite the existing cursor with a new one, which leaves the existing one open. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you should not be nesting cursor iteration this way and even if you do that, you should do it in a correct sequece.

1. Close existing cursor
2. Retrieve new cursor
3. Move new cursor to the first item by cursor.moveToFirst()

Comment: Is there any way I could use the same cursor / overwrite it in a right way so I don't have to make a whole new Cursor?

Comment: Its just the reference to the old cursor that you'd need to cleanup, from the code you posted, it looks like DatabaseManager.getAllDataDay(...) must be returning a new cursor always.

Comment: Yes but how do I use the same Cursor name (since the same name is going to be used in the "if" statement again) with the new data that I'm trying to get? Do I just close the CursorDan cursor and CursorDan = DatabaseManager.getAllDataDay(danString); again or?

Comment: you can refer to the new cursor with the already existing variable. Please refer to the steps I mentioned above.

Comment: Okay, I will try. You said "Retrieve New cursor" so I thought I need to use a New (different) cursor variable?

Comment: No, you can use the same variable, but with reference to a new cursor returned by your method.